# Hanging script and cmd won't close

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, cmd

I am trying to run a python script via cmd prompt on my work PC (Windows 7, Python 2.7). The script requires filepaths from different drives on my PC. I am correctly pulling all necessary filepaths and I press Enter to run the script but the script just hangs. The only thing that shows is a blinking underscore. I try to click the X to close the prompt but nothing happens.

I am not able to Ctrl+C out of the program either. I open up Task Manager and I am not able to End Task (nothing happens) or End Process (cmd.exe doesn't even show up in this tab). I also tried Start-->Run-->taskkill /im cmd.exe but nothing happens. The rest of my team has no problem with Python 2.7. The only way to get out of the frozen cmd is to hold down the power button. I do not want to have to keep going through this process especially since this is during work.  I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out:

1. Any idea what's wrong with the version of Python I am using?
2. How am I able to kill cmd.exe so that I can continue normal work functions without having to hold down the power button and waiting 5-10 minutes to reboot my PC?

Comment: Which version of python 2.7 are you using?

Comment: Can you provide some of the code that shows how you enter the code paths? Or a screenshot? And a sample input would be great

Comment: out of curiosity, how long does it hang for? are we talking hours? and what is the memory usage when this happens? and is there a performance drain on your machine?

Comment: I am using ActivePython 2.7.2.5.  Also, due to the nature of my work I am not able to provide code paths, code, or screenshots. I have looked at previous threads on Google and there have been similar problems in the past but these are threads that originated more than 8 years ago.

Comment: I did not wait to see how long the script hangs for. I do not have minutes to waste, let alone hours so I just hold down the power button so that I can continue other work functions. I am not at work right now but I will run the script tomorrow and take a look at memory usage/performance drainage.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have endless cycle somewhere in your code?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with the code because my coworkers are using the same exact python file without any problems on their PCs. I am convinced that nothing is wrong with the python code itself, rather there is a problem with how Python 2.7 installed or how cmd.exe is running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The filepaths I was pulling files from were through ClearCase directories. It turned out that I simply had to reinstall ClearCase. There must have been some configuration issue that was causing the cmd to hang and thus forcing a hard reboot. It's good to point out that I am no longer experiencing this problem and that nothing was wrong with the python scripts.